# Load balancing with stateful sessions

Tags: node.js, load-balancing, opa

My application is currently deployed in multiple instances and load balancing is performed with NginX reverse proxy.

The problem is that some request to the server may be very expensive. Sometimes single node is overloaded and every user with bad luck (directed by the load balancer to this node) will suffer very low response times.

Second problem is the software written with [Opa framework](http://opalang.org) with statefull sessions. All the requests from the user (including AJAX and server push implementation built into the framework) has to stick with the same node.

Neither load balancing based on IP hashing (like NginX with [ip_hash](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash) option) nor round-robin is a solution :(

I want to try Node's [Cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) which does not load balance in round-robin way, but relies on operating system to choose less loaded process for new request. Unfortunately, similar to round-robin it does not support sticky sessions.

My idea is to use Cluster to choose less loaded process by listening on common port and redirect to "private" URL - different for each process. Reverse proxy can translate name-based virtual domains `www1.mysite`, `www2.mysite`, ... into `mysite:8001`, `mysite:8002` etc. This way as soon as first contact is made browser will stay with the node assigned.

Node.js code of Cluster worker:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var master_port = 8000;
var worker_port = master_port + cluster.worker.id;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello ' + cluster.worker.id);
}).listen(worker_port);
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': '//mysite:' + worker_port + url.parse(req.url).pathname
  });
  res.end("Redirecting to worker " + cluster.worker.id);
}).listen(master_port);
```

This approach requires lots of changes in application, because I have to make sure all static resources are fully qualified URL-s (including server name) to be cached. NginX should be reconfigured especially for this app, so static files will be redirected from "private" hostnames/ports and will be visible in a single copy. Additional redirection also could increase response times for page load.

Is there better approach for "sticky sessons" with Cluster? Or perhaps NginX can somehow redirect to node chosen before based on some cookie or other HTTP header? Anyone already solved this problem before?

Comment: Cluster load balancing not as good as you may expect. Look at [this post](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/whats-new-in-node-js-v0-12-cluster-round-robin-load-balancing/).

Comment: @alexeyten I have done a quick test with Node v0.10.21 with just 2 worker processes. In case processes were idle one of them got most of the requests, but in case of one busy (active waiting with empty loop) the other got most of the network requests. That is fine for me, because in case thy are idle it does not matter which node will process. Perhaps it would change for greater number of processes... I have not tested the case, when both were very busy - them it would be preferred to distribute work evenly, and preference of any of them would be a problem.